# Include link to a file location in an e-mail in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to send an email from sas.

The body of the e-mail must have the link to the file location.

The I used the following sas code.

```
%let link = file:\\a\hello world\test\file location; 

filename testmail email "test@test.com";

data _null_; 
  file testmail; 
  put &link; 
run;
```

It is sending the email as expected but since there is a space in the address, the like gets broken at file:\a\hello

Any way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to link to a file in a shared location, you need to use the `type='text/html'` option on the email fileref, plus create the appropriate link... `<a href='file:\\a\hello world\test\file location'>Link</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

Sending email with SAS is a bit tricky. Here is a template that I've used mended to your purposes. It's not quite what you are after, but supports dynamic inputs.

```
%let resplist= test@test.com;
%let RepPath= C:/test;
%let Repname= Result.csv

FILENAME Mailbox EMAIL &respList.
/*      bcc=(&bccList.) Add any other delivery targets here.  */
        Subject="Test mail"
         attach=("&RepPath.\&ReportName.")
        type='text/html';

    DATA _NULL_;
            FILE Mailbox;
              put "<body>";
              put "<p>Good day,</p>" ;
              put "<p>I am an automagic mail.<br>";

    run;
```

Here are a few additional resources you might wish to take a look at [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002058232.htm) [A decent pdf on matter](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/038-2008.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the **log** output ?

A first fix to try is to double-quote the link in the put statement

```
put "&link";
```

instead of

```
put &link;
```

A second fix to try is to URL encode the link.

```
%let link = %sysfunc(URLENCODE(file:\\a\hello world\test\file location));

%* show encoded link in the log;
%put NOTE: &=link;
----- LOG -----
NOTE: LINK=file%3A%5C%5Ca%5Chello%20world%5Ctest%5Cfile%20location
```